# How do I filter out Dangerous HTML like SO does?

Tags: php, html, sanitization, html-sanitizing

I want to provide an HTML editor on my site, but don't want to open myself up to xss or other attacks that come with allowing user-generated HTML.

This is pretty similar to what Stack Overflow does. How is the HTML checked/sanitized here so that the styling information still remains, while other, more dangerous stuff (like javascript, iframes, etc.) are kept out?

Are there any libraries (preferably in PHP) that already do this?

Comment: Probably better asked at meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: The easiest way is to use a list of known safe and allowed HTML tags, rather than trying to filter out the bad things.

Comment: @j08691, andreas: Just because the question uses SO as an example doesn't automatically make it a meta question.

Comment: HTMLPurifier will do the trick; http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @Simeon Visser yes but that still leaves the question open of how to actually check the html. BoltClock Yes, thank you. This is not about SO specifically, I just chose it as the most familiar example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The general idea is to only allow some HTML tags (and some attributes).

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a function `strip_tags` that strips HTML and PHP tags from a string, and allows you to specify certain allowable tags. But as `@webarto` states, there are [libraries](http://htmlpurifier.org/) that do this better.

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: That is not the solution... http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: @webarto how to write for example `>` and `<` but make them visible in the result?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`...

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan: Since the input is already in HTML the user (or the HTML editor on the page) typing in the content would have to take care of escaping things like "<".

Comment: `strip_tags` alone doesn't answer the question correctly as it doesn't modify tag attributes. One can still abuse tag attributes if you use only this method. Make sure whatever solution you end up using sanitizes also attrs such as onmouseover, href, onclick... Best sanitization is no sanitization, if it suits your needs consider using a simple alternative such as markdown with safe mode on.

Answer (score 0):

*Your can use*

```
strip_tags($yourData,"<a><p><div><i>") // more tags you want to keep;
```

*If your using SQL too use*

```
mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

This is really all you need to not get injected. Do keep in mind, when using mySQL real escape you need to use [strip slashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php%20strip%20slashes) to remove them when you echo them out.

Here are the docs for [strip tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php%20strip%20tags) and the docs for [mysql escape](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php%20mySQL%20escape).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to allow some (X)HTML and restrict only tags viewed as unsafe, you can use something like KSES. Wordpress uses a solution like this.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/kses/

Answer (score -1):

In addendum to Whymarrh's post, suggestion is to have the code work take place in a subfolder of your site, and auto-alter any code that has "..", or "http://" or any mysql commands.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not a separate answer.