# laravel 5 ckeditor implementation server side validation

Tags: validation, laravel-5.1, server-side, implementation, ckeditor4.x

I apologize if a question like this has already been asked. I couldn't find one.

So basically, I am using ckeditor(the basic version) and laravel 5.1. 
I had no problem implementing it, I am just ultra paranoid about validating the information server side. I am using the blade template engine. In my view, when rendering the data, I am doing something like `{!! $something->info !!}`, not `{{ $something->info }}`, because I expect html tags such as `<a></a>`, `<b></b>`, etc.

Well what happens if a user types something like `<script>alert(1)</script>` or even worse ...

All in all, I am asking whether you can share some good practices, maybe using a function where I can say which tags are allowed...

Comment: Best practice is to never trust user. If you're displaying the user input without processing than you need to stick with {{ }} in your blade template.

Comment: That's what I am asking. How can I process it in a good way, so that the user can still modify the content he/ she is adding with different tags and styling and I can sleep tight without worrying about someone being able to hack my website?

Comment: well, you had to search with [sanitizing html input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853239/how-do-i-filter-out-dangerous-html-like-so-does) as keywords. hope it give you insight - especially the libraries they suggested. and, look at this [L5 Html Purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier) if you're too lazy to google the Laravel-based library.